# from web how to scrape link and text from specific part

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests, web-crawler

i have written code which scrape all the link from web , however i would like to only scrape 'Latest update' from https://www.bbc.com/news/coronavirus

This is how i tried

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
import requests

    def get_links(url):
        response = requests.get(url)
        data = response.text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'lxml')
    
        links = []
        for link in soup.find_all('a'):
            link_url = link.get('href')
    
            if link_url is not None and link_url.startswith('/news'):
                links.append(link_url + '\n')
    
        write_to_file(links)
        return links
    
    
    def write_to_file(links):
        with open('data.txt', 'a') as f:
            f.writelines(links)
    
    
    def get_all_links(url):
        for link in get_links(url):
            get_all_links(link)
    
    
    r = 'https://www.bbc.com/news/coronavirus'
    write_to_file([r])
    get_all_links(r)
```

Comment: Search only inside the div with class `gel-layout__item gel-3/5@l`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'lxml')
latest = soup.find(class_="class_of_the_div_wrapping_latest_news")
```

then you can go on with

```
links = []
for link in latest.find_all('a'):
    link_url = link.get('href')
```

Comment: Awesome - thx dear Nikita for this great solution. It helps us who are just learning Python !